# Do the Gloves of Flame require their user to speak Ignan?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, languages

The description of the Gloves of Flame in the Magic Item Compendium 3.5 states:

> In addition, five times per day you can utter the word "burn" in lgnnan to generate a flame in the palm of one hand.

Does a character have to be able to speak Ignan in order to activate this effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, the item functions the same as any other command word item.**

The character simply needs to know the word used to activate it, whether through being told, a hint on the item, or simple experimentation. Many command words don't even have any particular meaning. This part of the description for the item is simply for flavor.